# one project two apps (paid and free) on Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-sdk

I have an a PAID app on the store. Now I would like to distribute another free(2 apps: 1 paid and 1 free). Obviously I would not recreate another project.
you can do? on ios and android is direct by the project with the targets. you can on windows phone?
i use Windows phone 8.1 silverlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as on iOs and Android. Use `Conditional compilation symbols`.

[image]

and then in code:

```
#if FREE_VERSION
            TrialPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
#endif
```

Comment: No, do not touch them.

Comment: I'm sorry but this way does not give me problems when I go to publish because in conflict with that of the store

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I use the same way.

Comment: ok and how do you give two different names?
1) name = appname
2) name = appname free

Comment: In the windows phone store dashboard.

Comment: ok thanks I try. I do not understand how they work two versions with the same manifest and the same productid. I had read that it was not possible. your app as it is called so I can see if I have explained well what I need. i use win phone 8.1 silverlight.

Comment: I promise, I use this technique and it's works. My app [Upcoming Tile](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/store/publishers?publisherId=CEZEO%2Bsoftware%2BLtd.) have free and paid versions built from the same source.

Comment: excuse me my app is a win phone 8.1 silverlight and i have another file Package.appxmanifest

Comment: Build and upload to be sure that it's fine.

Comment: if i test in a emulator receive this error on launch: a resource specific communication (port) is already in use by another application

Comment: Test it in the windows phone store. You can submit two different versions with the same id.